# Why am I getting invalid "format" in logs while camera streaming?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, camera

I am getting this error in logs while streaming the camera in Android :
"GetYUVPlaneInfo: Invalid format passed: 0x21"

Here is my camera controller settings :

```
_controller = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.ultraHigh,
    imageFormatGroup: Platform.isAndroid
        ? ImageFormatGroup.jpeg
        : ImageFormatGroup.yuv420);
```

the error appears when calling start streaming :

```
 _controller.startImageStream((image) async {
 });
```

Comment: Can you solve the problem? I believe that some android devices can't use ImageFormatGroup.jpeg directly. I have a problem with some of my devices

Comment: You are right, some devices do not work with jpeg format so I check the device model first and use yuv420 instead of jpeg for some devices like "samsung SM-A528B" and "Xiaomi M2007J3SY".